# What does since_id in twitter API return when it is an empty string?

Tags: php, json, twitter, tweets

I would like to know what using since_id in Twitter API Search would return?
I have been repeatedly trying to get json data over our slow internet and testing different forms of the query. I was using the search api and tried assigning

```
since_id = ""
```

but then, after repeated trials most of the time i get response:0 but there are time response is 200 (which is successful). Sometimes i repeatedly run it just to make sure and found out the same codes sometimes return 0 or 200. So i guess it is just the internet connection.

In my results, the tweets that were returned were only those posted at the current date. I am not sure, i would like to confirm it else are there ways to get all the dates from latest to oldest? because i am trying to get the count of all tweets which mentions the word "dragon" from current date to the last month. 
I have tries querying first date all result using "until" last month to get the latest id till that time. then another query for "since_id" to current for the count. 
But due to some connection problem i am not able to tell if it works just fine .

Any thoughts please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `since_id` parameter is used for navigating through a user's timeline. If you submit a query with the `since_id` equal to some status id, your results will only contain tweets with a `status_id` greater than the one you specified. Since you are using the Search API, I would suggest instead using the [search operators](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) offered by the search feature itself. For example, the query "superhero since:2011-05-09" will return results containing "superhero" and sent since date "2011-05-09" (year-month-day).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. the parameter since was not included in the version 1.1 of Api Search so i never so it. only the until parameter. Does it really still work?

Comment: It will work up to a couple days prior to the day that you search. Twitter only offers a few days of tweets in its search index over the API. It isn't actually a parameter, it is a part of the search query itself. Check the page I linked for details.